# If $p$ is a primitive root modulo $q$ then $q$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p, q > 2$ be prime numbers of the form $p = 4k − 1, q = 4n − 1$
for some integers $k, n$. Suppose that $p$ is a primitive root modulo $q$. Show that $q$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$.

---

I can see that $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ which implies that $\left(\frac pq \right)=−\left(\frac qp \right)$. The thing I think that I am missing is the connection between quadratic residues and primitive roots. What is the connection here?

Comment: Hint;  Quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: I can see that $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $q \equiv 3 \mod 4$ which implies that $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = - \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$. The thing I think that I missing is the connection between quadratic residues and primitive roots. What is the connection here?

Comment: @anon_penguin:  What definition(s) of $\left( \frac{p}{q} \right)$ do you know?  What definition(s) of primitive roots do you know?

Comment: Hint 2:  Prove that no square can be a primitive root.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thank you so much for the help!